# DLGTEMPLATE gui editor as a library or a component

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm looking for a Windows (pure DLGTEMPLATE output no .net resources!) dialog template editor (as a library or component) that can be used to modify or/and create new dialog templates for DialogBoxIndirect() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows resource editor (part of Visual Studio) to create your dialog, then you can simply load the dialog resource to show the dialog.

You could also write some utility that reads the generated resource dialog and generate the DLGTEMPLATE data for it (I don't think it's that hard).

Comment: nah I'm looking for an inline editor I can use in my own application, with controls, alignment handling...